# How to report a bug and contribute a fix for juju

Tags: juju

What process should I follow as a user of juju or a developer wishing to contribute a patch or bugfix to the project?

The answer should include:

- How to file a bug and where?
- How to propose a patch against juju-core source?
- How to get a code review?
- How to submit an approved patch?

As juju is becoming more popular, people want to contribute, but the process is not quite well documented.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several starting points worth checking out: README.md and CONTRIBUTING.md files in the juju-core source (https://github.com/juju/juju) explain how to install and build juju from source and set up your Github account as needed. Whenever you have a question, there are several ways to get in touch with the juju-core team:

- on IRC channels #juju-dev and #juju on FreeNode (most developers hang out there daily);
- subscribe and send questions to the users and developers mailing lists (juju@lists.ubuntu.com and juju-dev@lists.ubuntu.com);
- checking AskUbuntu for questions which might be relevant (a lot of team members answer questions tagged with "juju" regularly);
- searching and reporting juju-core bugs on Launchpad (https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core) or (if you don't have a LP account - https://github.com/juju/juju/issues).

For more detailed answers to the typical steps in the workflow (file a bug, propose a patch, get code review, submit the patch), take a look at [Juju @ github – The Life of a Bugfix](http://blog.naydenov.net/2014/10/juju-github-the-life-of-a-bugfix/).

In the near future some steps of the process will be automated and get easier for contributors, so in the mean time I hope this helps!